# merge variables in unix

Tags: arrays, shell, variables

In UNIX:

I have a few variables:

```
FOLDER0=/home/user0
FOLDER1=/home/user1
FOLDER2=/home/user2
FOLDER3=/home/user3
FOLDER=FOLDER

for i in 0 1 2 3
do
${FOLDER}${i} // print /home/user0, /home/user1 and so on based on value of i
done
```

The value of ${i}${FOLDER} should print /home/user0, /home/user1 and so on based on value of i
Is there any way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**
Put the numbers at the end of the variable instead of at the beginning.

Comment: See http://www.codeislove.org/?p=12 and http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: thanks @cbuckley, pls post this as the answer, I will accept it. Exactly what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `eval`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

FOLDER0=/home/user0
FOLDER1=/home/user1
FOLDER2=/home/user2
FOLDER3=/home/user3
FOLDER=FOLDER

for i in {0..3}; do
  eval var=\${FOLDER${i}}
  print $var
done
```

Note: my loop was bash/ksh-specific, but the `eval` construct is not.